# How much time does TCP waits before retransmission?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

If I have a window size of 8 KB, then when 8 KB are sent to the other side and no ACK has been received, TCP will not send anything more until an ACK is received.

But what if an ACK is not going to arrive, how much time does TCP waits before retransmitting the data.

I believe that this depends on the implementation of TCP, so I am talking about Windows.

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170359.

Answer (score 1):

This value depend on what you set in [socketopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Default timeout for TCP is usually are between 30-60 seconds